# How to set the scale mode to stretch to full screen when using the VideoFragment to play a video on Leanback

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Google's [Leanback showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/media/VideoConsumptionExampleFragment.java) video player without ExoPlayer

Google's [Leanback showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/app/media/VideoConsumptionExampleWithExoPlayerFragment.java) video player with ExoPlayer

I've tried out the leanback showcase from google and it too plays the videos on "fit to screen" mode with black bars on the sides. I can't find an option to change the scale mode anywhere on the API docs either

Comment: You can change your layout view, add this line `app:resize_mode="fill"`. Check here(http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html) for more details. Using `resize_mode` controls how video and album art is resized within the view. Valid values are `fit`, `fixed_width`, `fixed_height` and `fill`. See also [this github post](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2317) for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to look into the `VideoFragment` source to figure this one out. `VideoFragment` has a simple `SurfaceView` as the root element of its layout and all you have to do is make the `SurfaceView` match the parent (which is the device screen) width and height. To do that just override `onVideoSizeChanged` and use `getSurfaceView` to get a reference to the package-private `SurfaceView` instance used in the `VideoFragment`.

```
@Override
protected void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height) {
    switch (scaleMode) {
        // `scaleMode` flag indicates that this video should stretch to screen
        case MediaMetaData.SCALE_MODE_STRETCH:  
            View rootView = getView();
            SurfaceView surfaceView = getSurfaceView();
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = rootView.getHeight();
            params.width = rootView.getWidth();
            surfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
            break;
        // When the video shouldn't stretch, just invoke super to have the VideoFragment's default behavior which is fit to screen
        default:                            
            super.onVideoSizeChanged(width, height);
    }
}
```